# JPA is creating columns by itself

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to map a table to a class using JPA

```
    @Entity
    @Table(Data)
    public class AllData implements Serializable {
      @Id
      @Column(name="AppID")
      private String appID;
      @Column(name="firms_bad_dt_in_last")
      private String no_of_firms_has_bad_debt_in_last_3_years_Including_credit_card;
    }
```

now when hibernate is connecting to database it is creating a new column with name no_of_firms_has_bad_debt_in_last_3_years_Including_credit_card instead of mapping it to existing column(firms_bad_dt_in_last). Did i miss some thing?

I dont want to create a new column, I want it to map to the existing column and get data from it.. how can I do it? Thanks!

I'm using spring-boot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to turn this feature off you can change the following hibernate property. Also, if you are using postgressql or any other DB which has case sensitive columns, then you need to check what case the columns are in.

```
<prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</prop>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the tables are not existed with in db then by default hibernate will take the attribute name and create the tables with those attribute names.If tables are existed with in the db then what ever the column name you mentioned in the db table must be same as the column name which should be mentioned at @Column(name="") then only mapping will occurs.